# To calculate maths operation in a column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, math, calculation, operation

I would like to use python to get final values for maths operation in a column of a CSV file, may I know is it possible to get the value as below?

Original CSV:

```
Type Total
A    2+2
B    (10/2)*5
C    5-2*3
```

Expected Output:

```
Type Total
A    4
B    25
C    -1
```

I have tried searching around but I could not get any idea on it...
All data are in string, I tried to convert to float but due to the maths operation, so it cannot be done.

Comment: You're looking for the `eval` method ... but make sure you look up proper application, as the older version is especially dangerous.

Comment: Hi Prune, thanks for the suggested method :) I will check on this function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pandas.eval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) with [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df['Total'] = df['Total'].apply(pd.eval)
print (df)
0    A    4.0
1    B   25.0
2    C   -1.0
```

Dont use:

```
df['Total'] = pd.eval(df['Total'])
```

because failed if more like 100 rows.

EDIT: If need working only for not missing values:

```
mask = df['Total'].notna()
df.loc[mask, 'Total'] = df.loc[mask, 'Total'].apply(pd.eval)
```

EDIT1: If possible some values which cannot be processed use custom function with `try-except`:

```
print (df)
  Type     Total
0    A       2+2
1    B  (10/2)*5
2    C     5-2*3
3    D       NaN
4    E       aaa

def func(x):
    try:
        return pd.eval(x)
    except:
        return x

df['Total'] = df['Total'].apply(func)
print (df)
  Type Total
0    A     4
1    B    25
2    C    -1
3    D   NaN
4    E   aaa
```

Comment: @Js_lfzr - Do you think missing values? Then test non missing values by `mask = df['Total'].notna()` and apply solution only for this values, answer was edited.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael , I have found my mistake :) . Thanks a lot for sharing these code, I able to learn more thing and simplify my code :)